# JavaScript typeof function passed as an argument returns undefined

Tags: javascript

The example below works fine, however, I am trying to make a function `handleArcs()` more universal (i.e. `handleLayer()`).

My `layerVar` has a property `onEachFeature`, which applies a method `onEachArc` to each feature of the layer. I want `handleArcs()` to take a function `onEachArc()` as an argument, but it does not work and when I pass it and check with `typeof`, the result is `undefined`. Basically it's a simple passing a function as an argument to another function, but it does not work in this case.

My first assumption was that something is wrong with the context `this`. But because `typeof thisShouldBeAFunction` returns `undefined` back I am not sure now what the problem is.

Any guesses what may be a cause of the problem?

```
function onEachArc(feature, layer) {
    if (feature.properties) {
        layer.bindPopup("<b>" + feature.properties.linkstr + "</b> has speed " + feature.properties.speed + ".");
    }
}; 

function handleArcs(data, layerVar, layerName, thisShouldBeAFunction) {
    alert(typeof thisShouldBeAFunction);

    //Add the feature to the map
    layerVar = new L.geoJson(data, {
        onEachFeature: onEachArc
        }).addTo(map);
}

getData('Layers/arcs.json').done(handleArcs(arcs, "Arcs", onEachArc));
```

`getData()` calls an jQuery AJAX method to get the data from the server:

```
 function getData(url) {
     return $.ajax({
              url : url,
              type: 'GET',
              error : function (xhr,status,error){alert("An error happened while loading a file: "+error+".")}
              });
}
```

Comment: **1.** The callback function to `done` is not actually _callback_, it is directly called, it doesn't wait for the `getData` to finish. Use anonymous function and call the `handleArcs` inside it. **2.** `handleArcs` excepts *4* arguments, you supplied only three, so the last parameter `thisShouldBeAFunction` is `undefined`.

Comment: @Tushar Edited my question to define `getData`. So, point **2** does not cause the problem. I understood the reason **1** why it does not work, but what solution is better - making  `handleArcs()` a callback function or solve it the way you suggested? Like what is a more "correct" way to handle this?

Comment: Please read the first point in the above comment again. Ive already mentioned problem and it's solution :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Tushar said, do not immediately call `handleArcs`, wrap it in an anonymous function with proper signature and pass that to `done`.

```
getData('Layers/arcs.json').done(function(data) { 
  handleArcs(data, arcs, "Arcs", onEachArc); 
});
```

I don't quite understand the point of

```
layerVar = new L.geoJson(...
```

inside `handleArcs`. You don't expect this assignment to affect `arcs` variable you pass in, do you?

About global variable as a parameter:

```
var aGlobal = "Test_One";

function TryToChangeIt(aParam) {
  aParam = "Test_Two";
}

function MyFunction(aParam) { 
  alert("Before: " + aGlobal);

  TryToChangeIt(aGlobal);

  alert("After: " + aGlobal);
}
```

By calling `TryToChangeIt(aGlobal);` we are passing the value - **not name** - of the global variable. A new temporary variable is created by javascript engine to serve as parameter and the value of `aGlobal` is assigned to it before `TryToChangeIt` is called. Inside `TryToChangeIt` we can change the value of this temporary variable, but this will not affect the value of `aGlobal`.

Comment: Thank you. No, I do. It's just I have several layers and I was trying to write a universal function, which can be applicable to any layer. `arcs` is a globally defined variable.

Comment: @EugeneKudko - assigning a value to parameter `layerVar` inside function `handleArcs` will not change the value of global variable `arcs`.

Comment: Oh, I got what you're saying. I guess it works only because this layer is added to the map now. But yes, you are totally right. It doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: I thought I understood what you're saying, but now, after thinking again about it, I am very confused. While doing that I followed this logic: I am passing a name of a global variable as a parameter to the function and then, because it's a global variable, its value will be changed in the body of the function.

Comment: @EugeneKudko - No, it will not. Try the example I added to my answer. Both alerts will show the same - unchanged - value of `aGlobal`. You passing the value - not the name - of the global variable.

Comment: I see. So, to change the value of the global variable I can just reassign it in the body of `MyFunction()`, by setting `aGlobal = "Test_Two";` . In this case the value gets updated (just checked it). But in my example if I call `getData('Layers/arcs.json').done(function(data){arcs=data})` the value of the global variable `arcs` stays undefined. It is wrapped in the anonymous function like you and @Tushar said earlier. Is it a special behavior of `done` which prevents me from changing `arcs` globally?

Comment: @EugeneKudko - `arcs` "stays undefined" because you are checking it immediately after `getData(...` line. `jQuery.ajax` is an asynchronous function, which means that `handleArcs` will be called later - when browser receives response to `'Layers/arcs.json'` request.

Comment: Yes, that point is clear. But in this case I am not even calling `handleArcs`. I was just playing around and trying to assign the received from `jQuery.ajax` value to `arcs` variable directly doing this by the anonymous function `function(data){arcs=data}` inside `done`.

Comment: @EugeneKudko - what I said also applies to your anonymous function `function(data){arcs=data;}`. It will be called asynchronously, and after it is called will the assignment of `arcs` happen.

Comment: I have read about asynchronous behavior yesterday from several different sources, including [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call), so I finally understood what exactly you were talking about.